# Killing listening process port X without knowledge about name

Tags: unix, port, kill

I would like to kill process that is listening on port 5000. I don't know how to do it because when I put:
`netstat -nlp | grep 5000`

I got:
`udp6 0 0 :::5000 :::* -`

so I don't know name of process.
How to deal with that in a such situation.

The question for:
1. CentOS
2. Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

If you see `-` instead of `(process ID)/(process name)`, that's because your user does not have permission to see what process is listening on that port.

All you have to do is run the command again as root (`sudo netstat -nlp | grep 5000`).

Example as normal user:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ netstat -plant | grep '0.0.0.0:22'
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Example as root user:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ sudo netstat -plant | grep '0.0.0.0:22'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14903/sshd
```

Notice that I can now see that process `sshd` with PID `14903` is listening on TCP port 22.